# Automate adding a Surface on a cut Mesh

Tags: mesh, faces

I am completely new and following some tutorials. I am preparing a Abyss Walker from DS3 for a 3D printer and splitting up the figure. I wonder is there any tool or option to automatically add a surface to a split Mesh?

[image: model in 3D view]

As you can See I split it to reduce the amount of supporting structures. It would be nice to avoid the hollow (pun not intended). Would be cool if there is an option to add surfaces where I cut it.

Comment: please show a screenshot so we understand what you mean  ;)

Comment: Try dividing the mesh into parts with Boolean modifier and cutting objects (cubes). If there are artefacts in the mesh it will probably fail and you will have to either do it manually or use volumetric booleans in Zbrush or Houdini for example (Houdini apprentice is free and support import/export of .obj).

Comment: You could also voxel the whole thing with a good resolution in something like 3D Coat. That would guarantee printable manifold geometry.

Answer (score 1):

Try the **Bisect Function**

**3D View > Mesh > Bisect**, requires a Face Selection

[image: Bisect Operator]

This allows you to split the mesh along a plane you can define by dragging, or numerically. If your Operator Panel is not open, hit F6 to show it.
It come with a bunch of useful options, like

- **Fill**, which fills the cut edges with faces
- **Clear Inner/Outer** which remove one or both sides of the cut
- **Axis Threshold** that gives the cut adge some fuzzines in where the cut-off happens.